# Django if statement with foreign key

Tags: django, if-statement

Cut it short I have a model called Page and a field called "parent" that links to itself, I want to write if the nav.parent has a parent called home then do this but for some reason it doesn't work.

```
{% if nav.parent == "home" %}
```

Comment: But what do you mean that the parent is "called" home? Presumably that relates to some actual field on the parent, in which case it's that field you need to compare.

Comment: I created a "Page" and called it "Home" from the title field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is of course that Django doesn't know which field to use when comparing, unless you tell it. Since "home" is in the title field, you need to actually specify that field:

```
{% if nav.parent.title == "home" %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in the template.

You have 2 options as a solution to your problem:

1. The bad one: pass the variables in the context from the view.
2. The best: create a custom tag which will receive `nav` as a parameter and find its `parent`:
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: @DanielRoseman You are right. I was in a hurry and I thought he was refering to a foreign key, something like nav__parent, not a field of the model. My mistake